# How to properly use NDK-Build in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-studio-2.2

**Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1** has a new external ndk build feature, but from `app/build.gradle` snippet shown in official blog post it's not clear at all how to set additional ndk build parameters which `Application.mk` file usually contains [image]

I'm able to set `Android.mk` ndk build file via `externalNativeBuild`, but how could I set the required `Application.mk` variables?

My `Application.mk` contains:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: Apparently [this is not possible](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210537) right now.

Comment: as a temporary compromise, you can modify your $(NDK_ROOT)/ndk-build to pass the path to your Application.mk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3 with updated gradle plugin added support for additional arguments. You can set Application.mk and additional configuration like this:

```
defaultConfig {
  ndkBuild {
    arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=Application.mk"
    cFlags "-DTEST_C_FLAG1"  "-DTEST_C_FLAG2"
    cppFlags "-DTEST_CPP_FLAG2"  "-DTEST_CPP_FLAG2"
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
  } 
}
```

If possible I would recommend migrating to CMake build system, because of better C++ code editor and debugging integration in Android Studio. You will find more info on gradle plugin configuration here:
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/external-c-builds.

**Edit:**
From Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5 you must wrap `cmake` and `ndkBuild` groups under `externalNativeBuild` group:

```
defaultConfig {
  externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      targets "target1", "target2"
      arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=Application.mk"
      cFlags "-DTEST_C_FLAG1", "-DTEST_C_FLAG2"
      cppFlags "-DTEST_CPP_FLAG2", "-DTEST_CPP_FLAG2"
      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
    } 
  }
}
```

**Edit 2:** It seems that  wrapping `ndkBuild` under `externalNativeBuild`  group does not work because of a bug in build tools.

Comment: While this might have existed in the preview it doesn't exist in 2.2.0 or 2.2.1 of the plugin.

Comment: @Cameron Lowell Palmer it exists, you just have to wrap ndkbuild group in externalNativeBuild group. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: @Tadas did you actually test it with 2.2.0 or 2.2.1 release?

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer I only tested with cmake group on 2.2.0 - 2.2.2. I did not test with ndkBuild, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

[add-native-code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {...}
  buildTypes {...}

  // Encapsulates your external native build configurations.
  externalNativeBuild {

    // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
    cmake {

      // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

> **Note**: If you want to link Gradle to an existing ndk-build project, use the ndkBuild {} block instead of cmake {}, and provide a relative path to your Android.mk file. **Gradle also includes the Application.mk file if it is located in the same directory as your Android.mk file**.