# NDK Build failing in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm having trouble getting my NDK to compile properly in Android Studio. Whenever I try running to compile I am getting the following error.

```
*Error:Execution failed for task ':Magic:buildNative'. A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''*
```

Someone please help. I have defined the path of my ndk in local.properties as

```
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Collo\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
```

and in build.gradle as

```
commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
'-C', file ('jni').absolutepath,
'-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
'all', 
'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9'
```

I have tried all i can and I am still getting the error please someone who has ever fixed this to provide the solution and in details please.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you invoking `ndk-build.cmd` directly instead of using the newly added `externalNativeBuild` block?

Comment: I have never used ndk before so am not used to what you are saying please explain further on how to go about it

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37765067/1524450

Comment: so it should work if I use  externalNativeBuild in invoking ndk-build.cmd in my gradle?

Comment: You'll have to try it to find out. But that's the method you're supposed to use. Your current method is deprecated.